# What's the command for SQL to change the date-format

Tags: sql

how can I change the Date format form YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY ? I tried this command:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10), @date, 101)
```

but it did not work. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What is @date? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using HeidiSQL and I want to edit the format of the variable of the type "date"

Comment: HeidiSql is just a managment tool, it's not a database. We need to know what database you are working with

Comment: Four answers and we don’t even know what exactly the question is!

Answer (score 1):

use format

```
declare @d date='2018-11-19';

select format(@d,'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=239d93f24980c16b59fe80137f7d642a)

```
date
19-11-2018
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Param1 DATE
SET @Param1 = '2018-01-31'  -- YYYY-MM-DD

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Param1,105) AS DesiredDate  -- DD-MM-YYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL：

```
Select CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 105) as 'DD-MM-YYYY'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4671fb88c96b32a833bcf9dbdf819208)**

```
select CONVERT (varchar(10), getdate(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

OUTPUT:

```
DD/MM/YYYY
19/11/2018
```